# How to make a div autogrow where contenteditable=true

Tags: javascript, jquery

How (using jquery or javascript) can I make `<div contenteditable></div>` autogrow when I type more text in it?

Comment: Let's start with you posting the code you've already tried.

Comment: Are you referring to its width? Because its height does autogrow.

Comment: No, in chrome a scroll bar appears. It is the height I'm looking to autogrow.

Comment: Doesn't `height: 100%;` suffice? Grows just fine in Safari. Issue might also be in an inherited style from one of the parent elements.

Comment: Does'nt it do this as default in all browsers ??? -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dV5DY/)

Comment: Have you tried `display: inline-block;` ?

Answer (score 15):

Avoid giving a `height` style property, and the auto-resize should happen automatically. If you must give a height, use the `min-height` property instead:

```
<div contenteditable="true" 
     style="background: #ddd; border: 3px solid #ccc; min-height: 60px">
</div>
```

See it in action: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T3NVJ/)

Comment: The min-height was great! Thanks!